# How can I run all NUnit Tests in Team City?

Tags: continuous-integration, nunit, teamcity

We are using TeamCity 6.0 to build VS C# solutions each commit.
Once the build is complete, a different test TC project runs. So that developers can add/remove/edit VS unit test projects, how can I make TeamCity use the the sln file or search for test dll's?
I don't want to have to edit the build each time a new test project is added to the VS solution.

**Run tests from:** `**\*Test*.dll` Doesn't appear to work, it only get s the first Test (which is currently failing)

[image: Build Step]

Comment: Is this a second build step or a different build? Do you use nant for your build or the VS build runner?

Comment: a) second build but the source is just shared. Would it help if it was one project? b) Nant I think.

Comment: Looking at the log, it might be trying to run the obj versions instead of just the bin versions of the dll's

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Fixed :) - 
RTFL (Read the log!)
**Run tests from:** `**\bin\debug\*Test*.dll`

Comment: Im using this and it double-runs tests, e.g. where two directories both contain the same DLL Foo.Bar.Tests.dll

Comment: In terms of double running tests presumably there is some shared test dlls? I'm having the same problem. Think I will try excluding them and then include a specific build step including the dll directory e.g. **\Shared.Tests\**\*Test.dll or similar

Comment: This will load tests only when your project is compiled in "Debug" mode. Change into "***\bin\\*\\*test\*.dll" to allow both: debug and release if TeamCity is not able to find the compiled test suite.

Comment: @HéctorEspíHernández triple star? (***)? What will that do? Thanks <3

Comment: @HéctorEspíHernández I expect it's a typo.
Run tests from any: `**\bin\*\*Test*.dll`

Comment: I found that this can cause a build failure when a DLL is found with no tests (Nunit 3)