# how to configure java junit with Teamcity?

Tags: java, junit, teamcity

Can somebody please tell me how to integrate java JUnit with TeamCity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jUnit task in your Ant script that you have TeamCity run.

Comment: Is there a way for those of us who aren't using Ant?

Comment: In the newer version of TeamCity you can add a build step to have your tests run by TeamCity - Like this, just use JUnit option - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646598/how-can-i-run-all-unit-tests-in-team-city-nunit

Comment: @OrnKristjansson I'm running the latest TeamCity, but I don't have a JUnit build runner.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same thing - without Ant.

Answer (score 0):

Current Teamcity version doesn't provide separate JUnit build step.

I guess it's because of test classpath determination problem.

You may provide classpath explicitly with [ant junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

Or Teamcity can fetch test classpath from [IDEA](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/IntelliJ+IDEA+Project) or [IPR](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Ipr+%28deprecated%29#Ipr%28deprecated%29-JUnitTestRunnerSettings) project. These two links explain how to run junit tests as part of compile build step.